# Set maximum width of dynamic iframe which is being added to dom

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a structure like this:

```
<div class="myfineclass">
   <iframe ... />
</div>
```

The iframe we embed comes from different sources, and we have little control over them. Sometimes we get an iframe which has a width of 640px, which is a problem because we cannot have iframes above 600px.

I tried adding classes like this:

```
 .myfineclass, .myfineclass iframe {
    max-width:600px;
}
```

But this doesn't help, and the iframe keeps being 640px.

What is the best way to make sure it suits our max width requirement?

Comment: Can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar that demonstrates this problem in action? Not sure why `max-width` wouldn't work, have you tried debugging the style with Chrome dev tools? You can see which styles are overriden, ignored etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use following CSS :

```
.myfineclass, .myfineclass iframe { 
    max-width: 600px !important;  
}
```